# No static method AnimatedContent - Jetpack Compose

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to animate adding/removing items from a `LazyList`. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64918640/jetpack-compose-list-diffs-animation) suggests that I use `LazyItemScope$Modifier.animateItemPlacement()` but I am running into issues.

I am using Jetpack Compose version **1.1.0-beta03**. Here is a snippet of the code I'm using:

```
@ExperimentalFoundationApi
@ExperimentalAnimationApi
@ExperimentalMaterialApi
@Composable
fun NotificationList(
    listState: LazyListState,
    notifications: List<Notification>
) {
    Surface(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        LazyColumn(state = listState) {
            itemsIndexed(
                items = notifications,
                key = { _, listItem -> listItem.hashCode() }
            ) { _, notification ->

                // ...

                SwipeToDismiss(
                    modifier = Modifier.animateItemPlacement(),
                    // ...
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, my app crashes when launched. Below is what I see in the console. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong or how to fix it?

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> Process: com.somecompany.someapp, PID: 22108
> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method AnimatedContent(Landroidx/compose/animation/core/Transition;Landroidx/compose/ui/Modifier;Lkotlin/jvm/functions/Function1;Landroidx/compose/ui/Alignment;Lkotlin/jvm/functions/Function4;Landroidx/compose/runtime/Composer;II)V
> in class Landroidx/compose/animation/AnimatedContentKt; or its super
> classes (declaration of 'androidx.compose.animation.AnimatedContentKt'
> appears in
> /data/app/com.somecompany.someapp-zQWcLTjkBOQqglBKnmHLIg==/base.apk)
> at com.google.accompanist.navigation.animation.AnimatedNavHostKt.AnimatedNavHost(AnimatedNavHost.kt:242)
> at com.somecompany.someapp.MainActivity2$onCreate$1$1$1$5.invoke(MainActivity2.kt:78)
> at ...

Comment: Could you paste the app build.gradle file?

Comment: Our build.gradle file, even `dependencies{}` is pretty massive. Is there something in particular you are looking for?

Comment: Same issue after moving to 1.1.0-beat03