# How can we animate addition and removal of items in a lazy list (e.g. LazyColumn)?

Tags: kotlin, animation, android-jetpack-compose, compose-desktop, compose-multiplatform

I had been struggling trying to get `animateItemPlacement()` to work at all in my application, and thought it was completely broken until I found other people's examples that seemed to work.

I've finally figured out how my app is different to the other examples:

- Adding an item to the list: doesn't animate, but I'd like it to
- Removing an item from the list: doesn't animate, but I'd like it to
- Shuffling all the *existing* items in the list: animates fine today

In the application I'm working on, shuffling never happens, so it took me a while to identify that shuffling did in fact work while basic addition and removals of items did not.

Self-contained example app:

(Sorry that it's Desktop only atm, that's because it's using UUID for the ID generation and I don't have a good cross-platform solution to that yet. I wish Kotlin would add UUID to core library... you can probably make a small adjustment to it to get it to work on Android too, but I think Desktop is the simplest platform to get an example to run anyway.)

```kotlin
import androidx.compose.animation.core.EaseInOutCubic
import androidx.compose.animation.core.tween
import androidx.compose.foundation.ExperimentalFoundationApi
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.padding
import androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.LazyColumn
import androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.items
import androidx.compose.material3.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.material3.Surface
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.material3.darkColorScheme
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.LaunchedEffect
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateListOf
import androidx.compose.runtime.remember
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import androidx.compose.ui.window.singleWindowApplication
import kotlinx.coroutines.delay
import java.util.UUID

fun main() = singleWindowApplication {
    MaterialTheme(colorScheme = darkColorScheme()) {
        Surface(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
            ItemPlacementAnimationMockup()
        }
    }
}

@OptIn(ExperimentalFoundationApi::class)
@Composable
fun ItemPlacementAnimationMockup() {
    val history = remember { mutableStateListOf<HistoryItem>() }

    // Some simulated activity
    LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
        repeat(4) {
            history.add(HistoryItem())
        }

        while (true) {
            val newItem = HistoryItem()
            delay(timeMillis = 1000)
            history.add(newItem)
            delay(timeMillis = 1000)
            history.remove(newItem)
            delay(timeMillis = 1000)
            history.shuffle()
        }
    }

    LazyColumn(
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(16.dp)
            // Uncomment the enxt line to align at the bottom instead
            // .wrapContentHeight(Alignment.Bottom)
    ) {
        items(history, key = { it }) {
            Text("Item $it", Modifier.animateItemPlacement(animationSpec = tween(
                durationMillis = 800,
                easing = EaseInOutCubic,
            )))
        }
    }
}

private data class HistoryItem(
    val id: UUID = UUID.randomUUID(),
)
```

**Is there any way to make `animateItemPlacement()` work for all three scenarios?**

I know I can use `animateContentSize()` to sort of simulate animating addition and removal, but it really is just simulation, and doesn't work for the case where you add one item to the list and remove some other item at the same time. In that case, the content size doesn't change, so no animation happens at all.

Comment: This only occurs if you add/remove the last item. There isn't any animation because only the items that change positions are animated, and since there are no following items that must be pushed down/pulled up, there is nothing to animate. What you want instead is to animate the added/removed item *itself*. [That's currently not supported out-of-the-box](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64922966) ([issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/150812265)). There are some hacky workarounds though that you can find in other answers to the linked question.

Comment: @Leviathan Thing is though, even if I have the items render at the _bottom_, it _still_ doesn't animate the items above it when you add/remove the last item - even though they _do_ move! I added a line to the code to demonstrate that. In the actual application, I do align them to the bottom. But also, if you fill the screen with items, adding an item at the bottom does push the items up. So I'm not sure the claim that there's nothing to animate is always correct. There is something to animate - it just isn't animating it.